How do I get rabbitmq management console logins to work correctly?
My team is evaluating the use of RabbitMQ, and one of the things we are serious about is our login security.
We have installed the rabbitmq management plugin, and it works beautifully.  But we are having some odd issues with it, specifically with login behaviour.
As it stand right now, when logging into the management console, any user/password combination you type (where it is a valid combination or not) logs you in as guest.  End of story.  We have been messing with this, reading documentation, googling the issues, and have not found the solution.  Here is everything we know:

We have NOT defined the default_user in the config file.  So it should be using guest/guest as the default user/pass.

We have created additional users, set their user tags to any and all of the different values for management console (management, administrator, monitoring, etc).

When we set the user tags of guest to "none", then nothing can login.  If we delete the guest user, noone can log in.

We have set appropriate permissions for the users we are working with.  Nothing changes.

Basically, it takes whatever we type during the login and assumes it is a wildcard combination for "guest".  Even when we remove permissions for guest, it just fails.


The instructions for creating a new user, including setting permissions and user tags is pretty straight forward.  Rabbit just doesn't seem to recognize anything we do.
Obviously, we cannot move ahead without figuring out the above.  RabbitMQ seems locked to the concept that EVERYTHING is guest user, no matter what is supplied at login.
